# Finding the second smallest value

Tags: stata

For every observation, I want to get the second smallest value of the last five observations of a variable.

Do you know which command I have to use?

```
* Example generated by -dataex-. To install: ssc install dataex 
clear 
input str5 var1 str26 var2 
"Value" "2nd smallest of previous 5" 
"8" "" 
"0" "" 
"4" "" 
"5" "" 
"0" "" 
"6" "0" 
"8" "0" 
"10" "4" 
"8" "5" 
"8" "6" 
end
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve], together with the expected output. Use the `dataex` command in Stata to provide sample data.

Comment: The qualification "For every observation" makes no obvious sense.

Comment: Yes, unless the OP provides more clarity i think s/he means the last 5 observations from a variable.

Comment: [CODE]
* Example generated by -dataex-. To install: ssc install dataex
clear
input str5 var1 str26 var2
"Value" "2nd smallest of previous 5"
"8"     ""                          
"0"     ""                          
"4"     ""                          
"5"     ""                          
"0"     ""                          
"6"     "0"                         
"8"     "0"                         
"10"    "4"                         
"8"     "5"                         
"8"     "6"                         
end
[/CODE]

Comment: Points arising from your data example: (1) the delimiters `{CODE]` and `[\CODE]` make sense only for Statalist: see the `help` for `dataex`. (2) Storing data descriptors in the body of the data, spreadsheet style, is quite wrong for Stata. The first observation's values should be variable labels. (3) Your variables are string and should be numeric. Use `destring` after fixing problem (2).

Comment: `[/CODE]` above.

Comment: How do I get the dataex part into a box?

Comment: Look at the edit to your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Original problem: 2nd of last 5

Another way to do it is that the 2nd lowest out of 5 will be returned as the lower quartile:

```
. sysuse auto, clear
(1978 Automobile Data)

. quietly su mpg in -5/L , detail

. di r(p25)
23
```

Revised problem: 2nd of previous 5

```
* Example generated by -dataex-. To install: ssc install dataex 
clear 
input data min2f5 
8 . 
0 . 
4 . 
5 . 
0 . 
6 0 
8 0 
10 4 
8 5 
8 6 
end 

mata:  
    mata clear

    real second(real colvector X) {
        if (rows(X) < 5) return(.) 
        X = sort(X, 1)    
        return(X[2])
    }

end 

gen long id = _n 
* install just once 
ssc inst rangestat 
rangestat (second) data, interval(id -5 -1)

list 

     +------------------------------+
     | data   min2f5   id   second1 |
     |------------------------------|
  1. |    8        .    1         . |
  2. |    0        .    2         . |
  3. |    4        .    3         . |
  4. |    5        .    4         . |
  5. |    0        .    5         . |
     |------------------------------|
  6. |    6        0    6         0 |
  7. |    8        0    7         0 |
  8. |   10        4    8         4 |
  9. |    8        5    9         5 |
 10. |    8        6   10         6 |
     +------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 2):

I think this is what you are looking for:

```
sysuse auto, clear

egen rank = rank(mpg) if _n > `= _N - 5', unique
egen low = total(mpg / (rank == 2)) if _n > `= _N - 5'

list mpg rank low if _n > `= _N - 5'

     +------------------+
     | mpg   rank   low |
     |------------------|
 70. |  23      2    23 |
 71. |  41      5    23 |
 72. |  25      4    23 |
 73. |  25      3    23 |
 74. |  17      1    23 |
     +------------------+
```