# Check whether a range contains specific values

Tags: stata

`Var1` is given. `Var2` should take value 1 if the Observation or one of the previous 5 observations is a missing value or 0. What is the Syntax for `Var2`?

I know how to do it with a lot of `if` Statements. But when I need to do it for the previous 50 observations that gets too inconvenient.

```
* Example generated by -dataex-. To install: ssc install dataex
clear
input float(Var1 Var2)
5 0
. 1
2 1
5 1
7 1
9 1
5 1
9 0
0 1
2 1
7 1
5 1
3 1
2 1
5 0
end
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Please edit your post to include what you have tried for the observations in your example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is similar to your previous --[Finding the second smallest value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51155287/finding-the-second-smallest-value) -- which you should quote. So is this answer. `rangestat` is from SSC.

```
clear
input float(Var1 Var2)
5 0
. 1
2 1
5 1
7 1
9 1
5 1
9 0
0 1
2 1
7 1
5 1
3 1
2 1
5 0
end

gen long id = _n 
gen Bad = inlist(Var1, 0, .) 
rangestat (sum) Bad, int(id -5 0) 

list, sepby(Bad_sum)

     +----------------------------------+
     | Var1   Var2   id   Bad   Bad_sum |
     |----------------------------------|
  1. |    5      0    1     0         0 |
     |----------------------------------|
  2. |    .      1    2     1         1 |
  3. |    2      1    3     0         1 |
  4. |    5      1    4     0         1 |
  5. |    7      1    5     0         1 |
  6. |    9      1    6     0         1 |
  7. |    5      1    7     0         1 |
     |----------------------------------|
  8. |    9      0    8     0         0 |
     |----------------------------------|
  9. |    0      1    9     1         1 |
 10. |    2      1   10     0         1 |
 11. |    7      1   11     0         1 |
 12. |    5      1   12     0         1 |
 13. |    3      1   13     0         1 |
 14. |    2      1   14     0         1 |
     |----------------------------------|
 15. |    5      0   15     0         0 |
     +----------------------------------+
```